# How to create a IP Address in TCP/IP network byte order?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-asio, type-conversion

I am using a raw boost socket to send TCP packets. (Compiling in VS2010)
My problem is that the arguments of the IP header for socket.send_to() are not valid.

I checked my own IP header and TCP header struct object and noticed the binary size is wrong. The problem relates to ip address fields for source and destination.

I am entering the IP address: 192.168.1.1, 255.255.255.255 and it works fine.
But if I offer the IP address 10.10.7.1 the binary result is wrong.

So let's see the struct, which stores the IP as unsigned int value:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct iphdrerer
  {
    uint32_t    saddr;
    uint32_t    daddr;
    uint32_t    baddr;
  };
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The IP needs to get convertet into binary format and big endian. I choose three different IP examples:

```
iphdrerer foo;

foo.saddr = (uint32_t) htonl(  boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("10.10.5.1").to_ulong() ) ;
foo.daddr = (uint32_t) htonl(  boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("192.168.1.5").to_ulong()) ;
foo.baddr = (uint32_t) htonl(  boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("255.255.255.255").to_ulong()) ;

std::cout << std::dec << foo.saddr << " HEX=> " << std::hex << foo.saddr << std::endl;
std::cout << std::dec << foo.daddr << " HEX=> " << std::hex << foo.daddr << std::endl;
std::cout << std::dec << foo.baddr << " HEX=> " << std::hex << foo.baddr << std::endl;

FILE* fout = fopen("foo.txt", "w");
fwrite(&foo, sizeof(iphdrerer), 1, fout);
fclose(fout);
```

The console output is this:

```
17107466 HEX=> 1050a0a
83994816 HEX=> 501a8c0
4294967295 HEX=> ffffffff
```

And I exported the struct object as file and opened this in a HEX viewer.
This is the result of foo.txt:

> 0D 0A 0D 0A 05 01 C0 A8 01 05 FF FF FF FF

These are 14 Bytes instead of just 12 Bytes. I removed padding by using  #pragma pack(push, 1).

Also the hex values of the file are not matching with the console output. 
The output should show me big endian address for TCP/IP.

Comment: The `0d 0a` is because Visual Studio is converting all your newlines (`0a`) to carriage return / line feed pairs (`0d 0a`). Using "wb" instead of "w" will stop this happening.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. So my struct is correct, but my arguments are wrong.